# how to remove primary key from result set in laravel mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I have following query

```
$tag_query = UserTags::query();
$tag_query->whereIn('tag_id' , $insert_data['to_device']);
$tag_users = $tag_query->get(['user_id']);
```

it is generating following result -

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 57da358e7ac6f6740e8b456a
            [user_id] => 57d67290823fb647dd174739
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 57da358e7ac6f6740e8b456c
            [user_id] => 57d672cb823fb647dd17473a
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [_id] => 57da358e7ac6f6740e8b4571
            [user_id] => 57d67549d81e1845e4dba983
        )
)
```

I don't want `_id` in result array , how can I remove it without using loop? 
expected output -

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 57d67290823fb647dd174739
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 57d672cb823fb647dd17473a
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 57d67549d81e1845e4dba983
        )
)
```

please help! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the `project()` method `$tag_users = $tag_query->project(['_id' => 0, 'user_id => 1])->get();`

Comment: Thanks much @chridam , it is working gr8!! , you can post it as answer. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply projections to your queries using the `project()` method:

```
$tag_query = UserTags::query();
$tag_query->whereIn('tag_id' , $insert_data['to_device']);
$tag_users = $tag_query->project(['_id' => 0, 'user_id' => 1])->get();
```